# A JavaScript Program where a number is generated and the user tries to guess it. My Issue is input

Tags: javascript, html

I have the randomizer working, My issue is getting the user's input. I can't seem to figure out how to trigger the input. I used "window.alert" as well as "console.log" but nothing happens. I'm very new to this.

**This is my HTML:**

```html
<DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <body>

        <h2> Guessing For Random Numbers! </h2>
        <p> A random number between one (1) and ten (10) will be selected. Try to guess the 
        result! Input your answer: </p>
    
    <script src= "RandomNumberMaker.js">
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**This is my JavaScript:**

```js
var number = window.alert("Please Enter A Number Between One and Ten: ");

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

if (random == number)
{
    document.write ("Your Guess Was Correct!");
    document.write(random);
    }else
    {
    document.write ("Your Guess Was Incorrect. The Correct Answer Was: " + random);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `prompt` to get a user `input` as sort of alert type

```js
var number = window.prompt("Please Enter A Number Between One and Ten: ");

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

if (random == number) {
  document.write("Your Guess Was Correct! It is" + number);
  document.write(random);
} else {
  document.write("Your Guess Was Incorrect. The Correct Answer Was: " + random + " not " + number);
}
```

```html
<h2> Guessing For Random Numbers! </h2>
<p> A random number between one (1) and ten (10) will be selected. Try to guess the result! Input your answer: </p>
```

Comment: Did you change anything in the HTML? Did I have something incorrect? I just made the edits you made here and despite it working perfectly here its still not working on my end for some reason. I'm using Notepad++ and Microsoft Edge if that makes a difference. I'm confused.

Comment: You might have made mistake in spelling of `prompt` . Else whole thing is almost same as your code but added some extra things for visuals of what number entered and some sort of stuff .

Comment: I have it spelt correctly. Your answer, Are these changes that were made done to both the HTML page and the JavaScript page or did you move what was on the JavaScript page to the HTML page?

Comment: Only changing `alert` to `prompt` will work out . Can you share the code which you are using , as it is running in the snippet than there might be some problem in code on your end

Comment: That's all I have. The code I sent is all that I have and I made the changes you recommended. The only thing I didn't include was that I was using Notepad++ to create said code.